# Angularjs function won't work with <div> element?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a number of `<div>` tags and I'm assigning them a function that allows me to display a kind of modal with details from the `<div>` element by changing it's css propriety '**display**' to '**block**' instead of '**none**'. for some reason the modal doesn't display when I click on the `<div>` element. but when I assign the same function to a button it does.

```js
$scope.CountryDetailStyle = {
  'display': 'none'
};

$scope.CountryDetail = function(idCount, nameCount, descCount) {
  $scope.detailId = idCount;
  $scope.detailName = nameCount;
  $scope.detailDesc = descCount;
  $scope.CountryDetailStyle = {
    'display': 'block'
  };
  // alert('idCount : '+idCount+' nameCount : '+nameCount+' descCount : '+descCount);
}
```

```html
<div id="pageContent" ng-controller="myAdminController">
  <div class="countries" ng-repeat="country in countries" title="{{country.descCount}}" ng-click="CountryDetail(country.idCount, country.nameCount,
        country.descCount)">
    <label> {{country.nameCount}} </label><br/>
    <img ng-src="uploads/{{country.image}}" alt="Image Not Found"><br>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <button ng-click="CountryDetail(country.idCount, country.nameCount,
        country.descCount)" style="display:block; float:right; clear:both;">Display Country Detail</button>
</div>


<div class="countryDetails" ng-style=CountryDetailStyle>
  <!--this is the modal i want to display -->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="boxHeader">
      <label>{{detailName}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="boxContent">
      <form>
        <p>{{detailDesc}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn" style="text-decoration:none;">Read More</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

can someone tell me what's the problem? thanks.

Comment: Could you post a link to working code? Here for example:https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your `div class="countryDetails"` is outside the `div` containing the `ng-controller` directive.

Comment: I'm using a php file to retrieve my data from server. I don't know how to upload that with the other files for it to work properly! here is the link [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r6qfn83w/)

Comment: @SergeK. in my script file I have to controllers and I'm using both in my html file. I'm adding the ng-controller to the <body> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, still don't know why it works but it does.  I moved the `</div>` of the div with the id="pageContent" to just before the body closing tag. That fixed everything.  Thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you should not display/hide elements based on some display: none condition. thats what ng-show (and ng-if) is for. Use a $scope variable like $scope.isModalVisible and set that to true or false.

Then you can use on your element ng-show="isModalVisible"

Comment: tried that too, still doesn't work with the `<div>` element. but it works fine with a `<button>`

Comment: @I_Nesrine please update your example and add missing parts. it's impossible to debug if half of it is missing. A jsfiddle or sth else were you can run the code would be nice

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myAdminController",["$scope",function($scope){
$scope.CountryDetailStyle = {'display': 'none'};
$scope.countries=[
{
idCount:"1",
nameCount:1,
descCount:1

},{
idCount:"2",
nameCount:2,
descCount:2

},{
idCount:"3",
nameCount:3,
descCount:3

},{
idCount:"4",
nameCount:4,
descCount:4

}
]
                                
$scope.CountryDetail = function(idCount, nameCount, descCount){
    $scope.detailId = idCount;
    $scope.detailName = nameCount;
    $scope.detailDesc = descCount;
    $scope.CountryDetailStyle = {'display': 'block'};

}
}]);
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head></head>
<body ng-controller="myAdminController" ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageContent">
        <div class="countries" ng-repeat="country in countries" title="{{country.descCount}}" ng-click="CountryDetail(country.idCount, country.nameCount,
        country.descCount)">
            <label> {{country.nameCount}} </label><br/>
   
        <button ng-click="CountryDetail(country.idCount, country.nameCount,
        country.descCount)" style="display:block; float:right; clear:both;">Display Country Detail</button>
    </div>

     <br><br>
     <div class="countryDetails" ng-style=CountryDetailStyle>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="boxHeader">
                <label>{{detailName}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="boxContent">
                <form>
                    <p>{{detailDesc}}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn" style="text-decoration:none;" >Read More</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you placed the `<button>` inside the `<div>` element?

Comment: country object will be available only in repeating container so that's why i placed button in div tag. Outside the container country object will be null

Comment: my objective is to display the modal when I click on the `<div>` element not the button. I only used the button to test if my function works.

Comment: so you can add ng-click for div